# attach image while sending emails

Tags: vb.net

I have this application where it looks for any jpg images on folder and if any jpeg found it sends an email to the client i can  send the data from the jpeg but how to attach image to the mail.
I tried this but received this error  system.io.__error.winioerror(int32 errorcode string maybefullpath).

```
Dim DirSearch As IO.FileInfo() = FileDirInfo.GetFiles("*.jpg")
            Dim FileInfo As IO.FileInfo

            Dim FileDir, FileName As String
            FileDir = FileDirInfo.ToString


 For Each FileInfo In DirSearch
            'for any files found, Split the filename into strings
            FileName = FileInfo.ToString

            Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
            attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileName)

                Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
                attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileName)

                Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
                Dim mail As New MailMessage
                SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("pramm", "roar")(//fake)
                'SmtpServer1.EnableSsl = True
                SmtpServer.Port = 587
                SmtpServer.Host = "email.loror.ac.uk"
                mail = New MailMessage
                mail.From = New MailAddress("alerts@loro.ac.uk")
                mail.To.Add("alerts@loro.ac.uk")
                mail.Subject = "Alert"
                mail.Body = "Vehicle " & VRM & " captured on " & Camera & " at " & TimeStr & " on the date " & DateStr
         attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileName)
            'mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
                SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for HTML-type emails and file attachments.

You can also put the HTML code to include the attachment as an  in the HTML code of your email.

```
''' <summary>
''' Sends the HTML-type email and possible attached files to the given email addresses.
''' </summary>
Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal fromAddress As String, _
             ByVal fromName As String, _
             ByVal toAddresses As String(), _
             ByVal subject As String, _
             ByVal body As String, _
             Optional ByVal attachedFilePaths As List(Of String) = Nothing)


    Dim oMsg As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

    Dim addrFrom As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName)
    oMsg.From = addrFrom

    For i As Integer = 0 To toAddresses.Length - 1
        Dim address As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(toAddresses(i))
        oMsg.To.Add(address)
    Next

    oMsg.Subject = subject

    oMsg.Body = body

    oMsg.IsBodyHtml = True

    If attachedFilePaths IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each path As String In attachedFilePaths
            Dim oAttch As System.Net.Mail.Attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path)
            oMsg.Attachments.Add(oAttch)
        Next
    End If

    '---
    'GENERIC:
    Dim client As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(emailSenderHost, emailSenderPort)
    Dim myLogin As New Net.NetworkCredential(emailSenderUsername, emailSenderPassword)
    client.EnableSsl = False

    client.EnableSsl = False
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    client.Credentials = myLogin
    client.EnableSsl = emailSenderEnableSsl
    client.Send(oMsg)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below helps.

- If the images are created by some process, then make sure the process disposes them properly. Or try by manually placing an image.
- Ensure that the application pool has permissions to the folder.

As a basic test you can create a sample directory under the root of your application, place a jpg manually. And then run the application, after making necessary changes to use this directory.